# Как отловить событие изменения масштаба в яндекс картах?

Tags: swift4, yandexmapkit, ios11

Как поймать в iOS-приложение событие изменения масштаба в яндекс картах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно стать стать слушателем `<YMKMapCameraListener>`

```
mapView.mapWindow.map.addCameraListener(with: self)
```

и реализовать метод слушателя, который будет вызываться при изменении положения камеры, при зуме карты:

```
func onCameraPositionChanged(with: YMKMap, cameraPosition: YMKCameraPosition, cameraUpdateSource: YMKCameraUpdateSource, finished: Bool)
```

описание метода в документации: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/ios/mapkit/ref/YMKMapCameraListener-docpage/